# How to temporarily disable rage shake opening the dev menu in react-native?

Tags: react-native

I'm developing an app in react-native for Android. I recently added a barcode scanning component. Whenever the scanner reads a barcode, the camera does a subtle *click* noise. It seems that this clicking is enough to trigger the "shake" required to open the developer menu.

Is there any way I can disable this shortcut programmatically? I would like to disable the shortcut when the barcode scanner is running and then enable it again later.

Comment: 5 year ago asked still no answer :(

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. A PR allowing this was recently (may/2017) merged, but only adds support for this on ios: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/13563

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You could try disabling the camera shutter sound though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run release version of an app. Run `react-native run-android --variant=release` for more details to generate signed apk follow guide [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can put the phone on silent mode, hope this helps!